# using string format for a credit card number

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, formatting

I'm trying to display a credit card number as a string like #### #### #### ####

I tried:

```
txtbox.Text = string.Format("{0:#### #### #### ####}", ccNumber);
```

and it didn't work.  Any ideas?

Comment: "Didn't work" isn't an error description. What is the result, and what did you expect?

Comment: Not all credit card numbers are 16 digits either, so be careful, some can be as low as 12, others as high as 20 digits.

Comment: I expect the string to have a space after four digits - 1234 5678 9123 4567  - and it looks like 1234567891234567.

Comment: The cc number being passed was already in string format - so formatting didn't work.  String.Format("{0:0000 0000 0000 0000}", long.Parse(ccNumber)) worked as expected;

Comment: John Batdorf is correct here - several card carriers have more or less than the "standard" 16 digits.  For example, American Express has 15 digits, arranged in a format of 0000 000000 00000.  Other international cards such as Maestro can have as few as 12 and as many as 19 digits.  You may need to take the card carrier into account when performing the display.  See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bank_card_number

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
String.Format("{0:0000 0000 0000 0000}", number)
```

**EDIT**

I paste my comment here to made it readable:

ccNumber is an Int or a string? 
if it's an int it should work. if it's a string you need to do a

```
String.Format("{0:0000 0000 0000 0000}", (Int64.Parse("1234567812345678")))
```

Comment: I expect the string to have a space after four digits - 1234 5678 9123 4567  - and it looks like 1234567891234567.

Comment: ccNumber is an Int or a string? if it's an int it should work, if it's a string you need to do a String.Format("{0:0000 0000 0000 0000}", (Int64.Parse("1234567812345678")))

Comment: Make sure the number is not already in string format!  once I converted to long, it worked as expected.

Comment: Major issue with using this though is all leading and trailing 0s will be destroyed.

Comment: @Chris Marisic String.Format only cuts leading and trailing zeros if you format with #### instead of 0000.

Comment: Arguably `String.Format("{0:0000 0000 0000 0000}", number)` is even more nefarious since that will turn a 15 digit CC into a 16 digit CC etc.

Comment: That doesn't work for 20 digit credit cards (Int64.Parse overflow)

Answer (score 1):

You better you a masked textBox, and set the mask to:

```
 this.maskedTextBox1.Mask = "0000 0000 0000 0000";
```

or set the string format to:

```
 long number = 1234123412341234;
 textBox1.Text = String.Format("{0:0000 0000 0000 0000}", number);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ccNumber.ToString("#### #### #### ####")
```

Answer (score 1):

ccNumber can be string

```
Regex.Replace(ccNumber, @"(\w{4})(\w{4})(\w{4})(\w{4})", @"$1 $2 $3 $4");
```

Answer (score 0):

probably easier to write your own function

```
getFormattedCardNumber(String cardNumber) {
    String formatted="";
    var chars=cardNumber.characters;
    for(int i=0;i<chars.length;i++) {
      if(i!=0 && i%4==0) formatted+="-";
      formatted+=chars.elementAt(i);
    }
    return formatted;
}
```