# Split a string containing 16 digits into 4 groups

Tags: c#, .net, string

If you take a look at the plastic in your wallet the 16 digit credit card number is broken into 4 groups of 4. Im trying to do the same thing,

Currently I have a string that has 16 digits but is formed as 1 single number. How can I add a " " after the 4th 8th & 12th number?

Any tips would be really helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5511846/formatting-string-in-mvc-c), using a [`NumberFormatInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.aspx):

```
NumberFormatInfo format = new NumberFormatInfo();
format.NumberGroupSeparator = " ";
format.NumberGroupSizes = new[] { 4 };
format.NumberDecimalDigits = 0;
```

Use as:

```
long number = 7314787188619939;
string formatted = number.ToString("n", format);
Console.WriteLine(formatted);
```

Or, if you're dealing with a string, you may choose can use a regex for a quick string manipulation. This will be easy to adapt to other characters:

```
string str = "7314787188619939";
str = Regex.Replace(str, "(?!^).{4}", " $0" ,RegexOptions.RightToLeft);
```

Comment: The OP has the "number" as a string, not an integer.

Comment: @Gabe - Already there `:)`. It's possible the OP just did a `.ToString` though, so it may have value.

Comment: nice one Kobi, the regex is a nice way to do it :)

Comment: string[] returnValue = Regex.Replace(forSplit, String.Format("(?!^).{{{0}}}", splitLength), " $0", RegexOptions.RightToLeft).Split(' '); allows passing 'splitLength' as a parameter

Answer (score 5):

```
var number = 1234567890123456;
number.ToString( "0000-0000-0000-0000" );
```

Comment: +1 Glad to see a simple solution to a simple problem. Some of the other answers are unnecessarily complex. At least so far, no one's suggested using a regex...

Comment: @Cody - Sorry, but I have a regex in my answer. As Gabe commented, the OP may have a string, not a number, so that may be a valid approach. Also, the OP wants spaces, not dashes, but that's an easy fix.

Answer (score 1):

```
string number = "1234567890ABCDEF";
int counter = 0;
var result = number
    .GroupBy(_ => counter++ / 4)
    .Select(g => new String(g.ToArray()));
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many answers.  Given a string `s=1234567890123456` the easiest might be to create a StringBuilder and append it. Untested code example below.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i += 4)
{
      sb.append(s.Substring(i, 4)); // Append these 4
      if (i != s.Length - 4)
          sb.append(" "); // append a space for all but the last group
}
Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

Comment: If you do `i += 4` you won't need your `if` statement. Don't forget that last set of 4 chars, though.

Comment: You're entirely correct, as I said it was untested - just giving a reference.

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this, an extension method

```
    public static IEnumerable<String> SplitToParts(this String forSplit, Int32 splitLength) 
    {   
        for (var i = 0; i < forSplit.Length; i += splitLength)
          yield return forSplit.Substring(i, Math.Min(splitLength, forSplit.Length - i));
    }
string s ="1234123412341234";
```

**s.SplitToParts(4)** should do the trick

Hope this works !

Answer (score 0):

Or if working with MD5 hashes, you could use an implementation like so...

```
       public string exHashMd5(string data)
    {

            MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
            md5.ComputeHash(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data));
            byte[] result = md5.Hash;
            StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
            {
                str.Append(result[i].ToString("X2"));
            }

 /// The implementation like so. (Below) 

            NumberFormatInfo format = new NumberFormatInfo();
            format.NumberGroupSeparator = " ";
            format.NumberGroupSizes = new[] { 8 };
            format.NumberDecimalDigits = 0;
            string rstr = str.ToString();
            rstr = Regex.Replace(rstr, "(?!^).{8}", " $0", RegexOptions.RightToLeft);
            return rstr.ToString();

 /// At the end you get yourself a nice 4 way split.
 /// Test it out. have a go with chucking it into a 
 /// MessageBox.Show(exHashMd5("yourstring"));

    }

 /// Could even go one further and add
     string hashtext;
     string newline = Enviroment.Newline;
     hashtext = exHashMd5("yourtext");
/// Then you do a simple command.
    MessageBox.Show(hashtext + newline + hashtext); 
/// Nice four way again. complex but yet made simple.
```

To work out what you need it to do, use maths. seriously, its mathematical. divide the amount of characters, till you are able to get a sum that equals four. for example, 32 / 8 = 4. then this will give you the four way split you need. basic maths. basic. basic. basic.